# Where does hamburger jquery button code go in Rails 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a hamburger button that causes a sidebar to appear and disappear. I'm using rails and jquery. I have included the gem jquery-rails.

```
application.js

  //= require jquery
  //= require jquery_ujs
  //= require turbolinks
  //= require_tree .
```

When I include the code directly in my view as:

```
  <script>
    $('.hamburger').on('click', function () {
      if ($('.sidebar').hasClass('open')) {
        $('.sidebar').removeClass('open');
      }
      else {
        $('.sidebar').addClass('open');
      }});
  </script>
```

it works! When I take away the script and put it in my xxx.coffee file which I've renamed to xxx.js, it doesn't work. I looked at the webpage code and have

```
 <script src="/assets/xxx.self-numbersandletters.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

I can't put together where I'm making a mistake. I think it might be that it comes together like:

```
  <script
    $('.hamburger').on('click', function () {
      if ($('.sidebar').hasClass('open')) {
        $('.sidebar').removeClass('open');
      }
      else {
        $('.sidebar').addClass('open');
      }});>
  </script>
```

but I guess I have to read more about the asset pipeline or convert it to coffee script.

Comment: Include your xxx.js into application.js

Comment: Consider this and check, $(document).on('page:change', function () {  put your code here};

Comment: Isn't it already included as part of the asset tree? I renamed the default xxx.coffee to xxx.js that was generated when I created the controller. And I think it works because when I look at the web page code I see <script src="/assets/xxx.self-numbersandletters.js ...

Comment: if xxx.js is controller's js then no need to add in application.js Asset pipeline will do it for us.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: Yes. I included the solution in the comment under the answer. I must have included a typo in my previous attempt. One thing I am unsure of, is if I have two .js files combining in the asset pipeline, do/should I .ready them both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xxx.js file

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
  $('.hamburger').on('click', function () {
    if ($('.sidebar').hasClass('open')) {
      $('.sidebar').removeClass('open');
    }
    else {
      $('.sidebar').addClass('open');
    }
  });
 });
```

Then include your xxx.js into application.js if xxx.js is not controller's js file.

```
 //= require turbolinks
 //= require xxx.js
 //= require_tree .
```

Comment: It was the $(document).on('ready page:load', function() { ... }); portion. I tried including $(function() { ... }); previously, and it didn't change the result.

Comment: It must have been a typo because now the shorthand $(function() {...}); is working as well.